# Multiple sorts operation triggered by 2 different select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to implement 2 different sort operation on two different columns of datagrid, Its becoming tough by using 2 different select boxes. I tried with below code, as I new to this i couldn't solved this...

```
In HTML:

<select  ng-model="reverse">
          <option  value="false">Top Sr</option>
          <option  value="true">Bottom Sr</option>
</select>

 <select  ng-model="reverse">
          <option  value="false">Top Rank</option>
          <option  value="true">Bottom Rank</option>
</select>


In datagrid:

<tr ng-repeat="items in empList | orderBy : ['-TR', 'SR']" >


In controller:

In controller : $scope.reverse = false;
```

Comment: Please show us how 'empList' object looks like. A little more explanation would be also nice - do you want sort first by column 'Sr' and then 'Rank' or should the last changed value have higher priority during sorting? By the way I think, you should't bind same model to two different dropdowns.. I think you should have different models for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you following solution:

```
<select  ng-model="sr">
          <option  value="+sr">Top Sr</option>
          <option  value="-sr">Bottom Sr</option>
</select>

 <select  ng-model="tr">
          <option  value="+tr">Top Rank</option>
          <option  value="-tr">Bottom Rank</option>
</select>
```

Then you should apply following ng-repeat statement to table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in empList | orderBy : [tr, sr]" >
```

And also set default values in controller:

```
$scope.sr = '+sr';
$scope.tr = '+tr';
```

You should substitute 'sr' and 'tr' with your objects (single element from  empList) properties names that you want to sort by.

When you modify $scope variables via selecting other option in select then it's automatically evaluated into correct orderBy statement, ex:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="items in empList | orderBy : [sr, tr]" >
```

Here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BqqYbcHgLfihYloeSqqg?p=preview). I've modified property name to 'tr' and now it works, but I'm not sure if that's what you wanted -> currently it'll sort by first column and only if values are equal then it'll compare objects by another property (which is 'tr').

UPDATE:

If you want to always sort by property associated with recently changed dropdown then you need to change a bit ([another plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UA6mX24qBgv6pgh4esJR?p=preview)):

1)add this initialization:

```
$scope.srRecentlyChanged = true;
```

2)add event on selects change:

```
<select  ng-model="sr" ng-change="srRecentlyChanged = true;">
          <option  value="+sr">Top Sr</option>
          <option  value="-sr">Bottom Sr</option>
</select>

 <select  ng-model="tr" ng-change="srRecentlyChanged = false;">
          <option  value="+tr">Top Rank</option>
          <option  value="-tr">Bottom Rank</option>
</select>
```

3)modify orderBy expression:

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in empList | orderBy : (srRecentlyChanged? sr : tr)" >
```

Comment: Hi thanks for solution, tried with one plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/pEbvGeag9xYHy5O3VMZn?p=preview. some how i can't  manage to correct it with object elements, could you please look into it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, is this the behaviour that you want or do you want to always trigger sort by select that was changed previously?